# How to get plot with lines output in R while knitting the document?

Tags: r, plot

I am getting output in R Markdown for plot code in Chunk. But I am not getting output for the lines followed by plot in R Markdown file

Show in New Window

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) :
plot.new has not been called yet
```